# CDF of sum of two squared correlated Gaussian variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Known $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_{x}, \sigma_{x}^{2})$, $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_{y}, \sigma_{y}^{2})$, $\mathcal{N}$ denotes normal distribution. However, $X,Y$ is correlated. Now I want to calculated the CDF of $Z$, where $Z = X^2 + Y^2$. Can anyone help me ? Any hint is appreciable.

Comment: Do we know anything specific about how they are correlated? As described this is similar to wanting the distribution of the sum of two correlated chi-squared RV's (except they are not standard normal).

Comment: This distribution is called [generalized chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution), and no, this does not help in any way to know it is.

Answer (score 0):

You integrate the joint density over a disk of radius $\sqrt{z}$.  I doubt very much that there is a closed form in general.